# ios5 core data: nsfetchresultcontroller refresh uitable

Tags: core-data, ios5, storyboard

i'm working on an app with core data with storyboard. the app has uitabbarcontroller as rootview. i have created entity and generated the classes. each tab has it own uinavigation controller. the view in the tab 1 just saves some data in the database from uilabels. and it works fine and data is in the database.
the view in tab 2 displays the data from the database in uitableview. the data is only shown when i kill the app and restart it. so the ui table doesnt get refreshed.
first method: i have passed the managedobject context from the app delegate to the both views. so ui table doesnt get refreshed till kill and restart.
second method: i (mis)used the app delegate, but still the same result.

```
MyApplicationDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

how can one achieve that one view only adds data to core data(which it does right now) and the second view get notified of changes and display it in uitableview?

### edit

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController
{
if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return __fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favis" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"chapterid" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Master"];
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;


NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

return __fetchedResultsController;
}
```

it is the code when you use the core data template. only tweaked to work with my app. i have it in my both viewcontroller.

### edit 2

i have implemented [nsfetchedresultcontroller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) in my uitableview controller.
the manged object returns the exact number of data in the database, but ui table doesnt get refreshed. i also did `[self.tableview reloaddata]` but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the viewController with the UITableVIew implement the methods for the [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). The documentation has the full implementation of those methods.

And then make your viewController the delegate of the NSFetchedResultsController `fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;`

Comment: i have set the fetchedResultsController.delegate = self; and have those 3 methods too. the managed object context count returns the exact number of data from the database but it doesnt get displayed

Comment: i went over it again. i dont know what was wrong in nsfetchresultcontrollor and i had tableview beginupdate in wrong place. but works now perfectly. and i misused the sharedapp delegate to set managed object context i my views.dont know if its best practice.

Comment: Somehow you may have had two different managed object contexts. Also, sounds like you need to save the context as you exit tab 1.

Answer (score 1):

There should be some thing in 2 tab as to notify as data changed in database update the new data, Is there any? If

`NSManagedObjectContext, NSFetchedResultsController`  in 2 tab by saying 
Implement `NSFetchedResultsController` delegation methods.

in appdelegate

```
secTab.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

Surely it works now

Comment: yes as i have written in my post i do pass the managedobjectcontext from app delegate to both views. but it doesnt refresh.

Comment: Is there any mechanism to notify changes from 1 tab to 2 tab?
Generally the mechanism would be notifications or NSFetchedResultsController delegation methods.

Comment: that's my question how to do it. i do have nsfetchresultcontroller. please see my question i'm updating.